# How to add model predictions to a dataframe or tibble

Tags: r, modeling, gaussian-process

I've run a model from the GpGp R package that outputs a series of predictions (by lat, long coordinates) for a single year or season across a lake. The model runs fine and I can even plot the predictions, but am having trouble putting the predictions into a dataframe or table (so I can take the numbers and actually compare them to a yearly average for my real values). I'm more familiar with tidyverse than base R so this may be part of the problem.

Here's the real data I used in the model:

```
> head(MI_LatLongDepth)
# A tibble: 6 × 10
   year season lake     station AvgDens AvgBmss_mg basin depth_m   lat  long
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2015 Summer Michigan MI49b      5.73       2.06 Gree…    40    45.5 -87.0
2  2021 Summer Michigan CS9564   167.       409.   Midd…   134.   43.6 -87.3
3  2007 Spring Michigan MI23      37.5       40.8  Midd…    93.4  43.1 -87.0
4  2009 Spring Michigan MI23      24.5       59.7  Midd…    93.4  43.1 -87.0
5  2011 Spring Michigan MI23      14         32.1  Midd…    93.4  43.1 -87  
6  2013 Spring Michigan MI23      40.1       35.5  Midd…    90    43.1 -87.0
```

And here's a tibble for the locations and depths at which the AvgDens was predicted by the model:

```
> head(mi_matrix_clean)
       lat      long  depth_m
1 46.03333 -85.60000 0.043701
2 46.03333 -85.59917 3.043701
3 46.03333 -85.59833 0.243698
4 46.03333 -85.59750 0.843704
5 46.03333 -85.59667 1.343704
6 46.03333 -85.59583 1.643707
```

I set up various season objects so I can get an output by year (such as 2022) or year and season (2022 spring or 2022.25)

```
MI_LatLongDepth$season_numeric = NA

MI_LatLongDepth$season_numeric[MI_LatLongDepth$season == "Winter"] = 0

MI_LatLongDepth$season_numeric[MI_LatLongDepth$season == "Spring"] = 0.25 

MI_LatLongDepth$season_numeric[MI_LatLongDepth$season == "Summer"] = 0.50 

MI_LatLongDepth$season_numeric[MI_LatLongDepth$season == "Fall"] = 0.75
```

I created one year+season object to use in the model (year_fraction):

```
MI_LatLongDepth$year_fraction = MI_LatLongDepth$year + MI_LatLongDepth$season_numeric
```

I set up the model variables, Y is AvgDens, what I am predicting, X adds the major variable, depth, and locs_time (coordinates and year_fraction)

```
locs_time <- as.matrix(MI_LatLongDepth[,c("long", "lat", "year_fraction")])

X <- model.matrix(~ depth_m, data = MI_LatLongDepth) #adds intercept

Y <- MI_LatLongDepth$AvgDens
```

Full model:

```
mod_time = fit_model(Y, locs_time, X, covfun_name = "exponential_spheretime")
```

Setting up predictions at new locations from a subset of mi_matrix_clean (just has a large number of lat, long, depths across the lake):

```
rows = sample(1:nrow(mi_matrix_clean), 50000)

mi_matrix_clean_subset = mi_matrix_clean[rows,]

locs_pred = as.matrix(mi_matrix_clean_subset[,c("long", "lat")])

X_pred = model.matrix(~mi_matrix_clean_subset$depth_m)

pred = predictions(mod, locs_pred = locs_pred, X_pred = X_pred)
```

Making the predictions for AvgDens at new locations:

```
locstime_pred2022.25 = cbind(locs_pred, rep(2022.25, nrow(locs_pred)))
pred_time2022.25 = predictions(mod_time, locs_pred = locstime_pred2022.25, X_pred = X_pred)
```

I'm easily able to plot these predictions, as below, but am unsure of how to best put them into a dataframe or tibble. Anything I can use to extract the actual predicted values for AvgDens.

```
quilt.plot(locs_pred[,1], locs_pred[,2], pred_time2022.25, zlim = c(-50, 300))
```

Comment: You might find function `augment` from package {broom} helpful: https://broom.tidymodels.org/articles/broom.html#tidying-functions